# Is there an option to prevent the cross validation (and gridsearchCV) to randomize the rows of the dataset?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

anyone knows if there is a way to prevent the grid search function `gridsearchCV` in scikitlearn to randomize the record of my dataset?

I have group of rows which correspond to a same phenomenon and I would like to randomize on the phenomenon ID instead than of the whole rows. I managed to randomize already on the phenomenon with SQL, now I just would like `gridsearchCV` to not re-randomize before separating the dataset in train and test sets.

Example of my dataset:

```
id time feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4 
A 1 b c s a
A 2 b a s t
A 3 q w o j
B 1 l o j f
B 2 9 k l h
C 1 o k h u
C 2 o k h i
C 3 p j g d
D 1 l l d s
D 2 ...
D 3 ...
D 4 ...
D 5 ...
```

I wouldn't like a splitting on the IDs between training and test dataset.

Is there an option which could help me?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridSearchCV` has a `cv` parameter that takes a cross-validation object; this must be an iterable that yields a pair of index arrays `train_index, test_index`. The standard `KFold` behaves as follows:

```
>>> from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
>>> threefold = KFold(n=10, n_folds=3)
>>> for train, test in threefold:
...    print("train: %r" % train)
...    print("test:  %r" % test)
...     
train: array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
test:  array([0, 1, 2, 3])
train: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9])
test:  array([4, 5, 6])
train: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
test:  array([7, 8, 9])
```

So you have to mimick this somehow, by implementing a class

```
class CustomCV(object):
    def __init__(self, ids, n_folds):
        """Pass an array of phenomenon ids"""
        self.ids = ids
        self.n_folds = n_folds

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self.n_folds):
            train = make_a_boolean_mask_for_the_training_set()
            test = np.logical_not(train)
            yield np.where(train)[0], np.where(test)[0]
```

where you'll have to fill in the logic of `make_a_boolean_mask_for_the_training_set` yourself. If it helps, I have a [variant for sequence data](https://github.com/larsmans/seqlearn/blob/master/seqlearn/evaluation.py#L90) online.

Be sure to also set the `GridSearchCV` parameter `iid` to `False`, or you'll get skewed results.

Comment: Hello larsmarns. Thank you for your help. I think your method is the correct one. I have been writing a class, and I would like to test it: https://github.com/foebu/mypythoncontributions/blob/master/myCVclass.py
What should I get out of it, the sets themselves or the masks to create the sets?

Comment: @foebu The indices of the samples in `X, y`. `np.where` transforms boolean masks into indices, as I showed in the example.

Comment: In the meanwhile I'm using the KFold, I didn't have time to implement and correct my class. Tt shouldn't be a problem to have some ids split on a dataset of 30K rows..

Answer (score 0):

Configuring something that does more step at once is hard (and I'm not sure it's possible here) - maybe the specialized method gridSearchCV isn't right for you if you want to do something differently. So I suggest that you split up these steps, which aren't too complicated.

1. Split the data for a cross validation to your liking, maybe using one of the sklearn.cross_validation methods.
2. Do the grid search, maybe using sklearn.gridsearch.ParamaterGrid.

Comment: Hi w.m., thank you for your answer. The first part I think is doable, but then, applying the gridsearch I get again my data reshuffled because the methods creates training and test sets itself, reshuffling. Right? Or am I wrong?

Comment: I just meant to say that both cross validation and grid search aren't overly complex things - you can do them in a couple of lines of Python. Whatever scikit method shuffles data in a way that you don't like, replace it by something you write yourself. I'm not very familiar with the scikit methods, but lucky for you @larsmans seems to have the answer how to do that in practice.

Comment: Thank you w.m :) Effectively creating manually cross validation sets is not that difficult and I think not even creating a gridsearchCV scheme, even though I didn't look at the code. But if there is the possibility to create something more flexible are re-usable it would be better